# What does T-SQL msdb.dbo.RestoreHistory Restore_Type NULL mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In msdb.dbo.RestoreHistory, the Restore_Type can be NULL.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/restorehistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**restore_type** / char(1) / Type of restore operation

- D = Database
- F = File
- G = Filegroup
- I = Differential
- L = Log
- V = Verifyonly
- Can be NULL.

I understand what D to V stand for.

However what kind of DB restore history record would have restore type NULL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The column is `NULL`able on the table, so technically that column can be `NULL` because no constraint enforces otherwise--that's what the docs are defining.

However, there is no scenario where you would expect SQL Server to intentionally save a `NULL` restore type.